# MySQL to SQL Server 2014

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have the below query:

```
SELECT Date(time) AS date, COUNT(*) AS total FROM branches INNER JOIN
stats ON branches.branch_id = stats.branch_id WHERE stats.time BETWEEN
'$from' AND '$to' AND branches.bgroup='$group' GROUP BY date;
```

But when I run this query on SQL Server I get the error:

> error SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]'Date' is not a recognized built-in function name.

How do I convert to SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server has no `date()` function.  Use `cast()` instead:

```
SELECT CAST(time as DATE) AS dte, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM branches INNER JOIN
     stats
     ON branches.branch_id = stats.branch_id
WHERE stats.time BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' AND
      branches.bgroup = '$group'
GROUP BY CAST(time as DATE)
ORDER BY CAST(time as DATE);
```